# tomcat eclipse java spring not possible for debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, debugging, tomcat8

Since two days it is not possible to debug my application, normally I use tomcat 8.0.27 for my project. When I use 8.0.39 it also does not work for the same project. I cleaned it, cleaned working space, delete it, installed it again and still it does not work.
When I try it with another project in another workspace, it works well ...

[screen print error message tomcat eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpPfC.png)

Comment: can you check if any war is deployed, try to manually copy the war and start the tomcat from command line

Comment: What's the message of that NamingException? Does the app run but not debug? Not run at all?

Comment: If it works in another workspace then go that route and save some time.

Comment: When I run the app it works, but debugging does not work ...

Comment: Ok Adam, I did what you adviced me and it works ok, now ...